# Cycle through a directory and get paths of all the files and folders

Tags: macos, cocoa, loops, file-management

Hello there im stuck on this thing where i need to cycle through a certain `dir` that i need to get all the file names from and get there paths as a variable.

I know how to create a loop, but to get the directory's contents, I do not.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Look at the NSFileManager class there are methods in there to help you.

Comment: I know about NSFileManager, Im just stuck with how to use it in order to get the paths of the files

Comment: `enumeratorAtPath:' (for example) does that not tell you anything? The doc even has sample code

Comment: You could read the documentation for NSFileManager.  Note that it has a list of methods that do things.  Some of them return lists of files, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try like this:

```
// If your folder is a document.
NSString *docsDir = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:  @"Documents"];
// else you can give your folder path as well, if you know 
// for example like this NSString *docsDir = @"user/desktop/testFolder"

NSFileManager *localFileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSDirectoryEnumerator *dirEnum = [localFileManager enumeratorAtPath:docsDir];
NSString *file = nil;
NSData *fileContents = [NSData data];
while ((file = [dirEnum nextObject])) 
{
   NSLog(@"your file name%@",file); // This will give your filename
   // Now for getting file path follow below.
   // here we are adding path to filename.
   NSString *fileNamePath = [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:file];
   NSLog(@"your fileNamePath%@",fileNamePath); // This will give your filename path
   fileContents = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:fileNamePath]; // This will store file contents in form of bytes

}
```

Hope it helps:)

Comment: I do not know why this got 2 negative votes but this worked and helped me a lot! Thanks! +1

Comment: @hussain-shabbir I tried your solution with path like this @"/Users/myUser/Downloads/" but dirEnum always returns nil. Do you know why ?

Comment: Just pass Downloads and check??